# How to set up the Context for an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In our old ASP.NET application, we had the concept of "Context" which was any data that the web page might require.  So, the Context could contain data about the Site itself and it could contain details of the End Use, *etc*, *etc*.

The complete Context was loaded by an HttpModule during the start of the Request's life cycle.  Each part of the Context was held either in Cache or in the Current Items Collection (depending on how long we wanted to hold the info for).  The Page would make a call to the Context as and when it was required.

So, I'm wondering how best to achieve something similar in .NET Core.

If we take the trivial example of the End User's data....

My thought was that this data could be held in an object called "EndUser".  The Controller's constructor could have an argument of type IEndUser, and we could use the built in Dependency Injection to add an instance of this in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IEndUser, EndUser>();
```

This of course adds a vanilla EndUser object, but I hoped that I could use a MiddleWare class to first set all its properties.....since I'm using "AddScoped" then my hope was that the Controller's Constructor would receive the same instance that the MiddleWare had just populated.  However, I soon realised that these are different objects (rather obviously in hindsight) and that this was the wrong approach.

So: what would be the right approach?  Bear in mind the following:

- With the old HttpModule, one could load the Site object (similar in concept to the EndUser object) (loading data from the DB) and within the HttpModule check if the site.OnMaintenance property was true, in which case perform a redirect to an appropriate page irrespective of the current Request and before execution has entered the requested Controller.

So to summarise, I'd like:

1. my MiddleWare to create a class and populate its properties (from a database)
2. my MiddleWare to perform tests on the properties of that class, potentially perform a Redirect.
3. If no redirect, then inject that instance into the constructor of my Controller.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of ASP.NET Core is different, as you've noticed. Having a context object (that approaches "god object") status was common in ASP.NET but is not the right approach in ASP.NET Core.

Without knowing much about how your application is structured, I'd suggest the following:

1. Create a `MaintenanceNoticeService` that is added to the DI container. This service would encapsulate all the logic needed to check the database for the `OnMaintenance` flag.
2. Create a simple middleware that sits above MVC in the pipeline that uses the service to check the state of your site. If necessary, you can redirect here.
3. Create **separate** services for things like accessing the user data. These can be injected into controllers as necessary.

The goal should be to break things down into small logical parts. Having a Context object that handles both checking for site maintenance and is also injected into controllers to provide user data is mixing concerns.